# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Send_Keys'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

I can't automate my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\New folder\Programming\chrome driver\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("search")

search.Send_Keys("fish")
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Send_Keys'
```

Snapshot:

[image: any help please.]

Comment: Edit: make the code clearer to anyone looking

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\New folder\Programming\chrome driver\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("search")

search.Send_Keys("fish")   

ERROR : 
  search.Send_Keys("fish")
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Send_Keys'



YOU can see the screenshot too

Answer (score 1):

```
search.send_keys()
```

Python, as most languages, is case sensitive. Not that experienced with selenium but after a quick search that might be it.

Answer (score 1):

### send_keys()

[`send_keys(*value)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) simulates typing into the element.

To simualate sending a *character sequence* within an element you need to:

- *Python*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_id("search").send_keys("fish")
  ```
- *Java*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys("fish");
  ```
- *C#*:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.Id("search")).SendKeys("fish");
  ```
- *VBA*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementById("search").SendKeys ("fish")
  ```
- *Ruby*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(id: 'search').send_keys 'fish'
  ```
- *JavaScript*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id('search')).sendKeys('fish');
  ```
- *Kotlin*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys("fish")
  ```